# Getstream location based feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I am try to implement location based feed in React Native app with getstream. For example user in New York only see only see feed post from other user in New York. If user in LA then user only see feed post from other user in LA.

So I am use geolocation. This possible with getstream?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it:

- add a custom property to activities and read the feed and ignore unrelated
- add activities to different feed, simply decide while writing. For example, if an activity should be seen by LA, then write it to LA feed
- contact support for personalization (paid though)

Comment: Thanks for reply! So I can add `'location': { 'type': 'point', 'coordinates': [37.769722,-122.476944] }` and then run query for only activity with nearby location? Like in you example? https://getstream.io/docs/adding_activities/?language=js